# special cell borders in iText

Tags: itext

I would like to create a table with two cells with borders that take the corners and half the middle section:
[image]

I played around with dashed lines but to no avail. If some could point me to the right direction, that would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the borders of the cell to `NO_BORDER` and use a cell event to draw custom borders. You can find some examples [here](http://itextpdf.com/themes/keyword.php?id=201).

Take for instance the [PressPreviews](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=95) example. It defines the following cell event:

```
public class MyCellEvent extends PdfPCellEvent {
    public void cellLayout(PdfPCell cell, Rectangle position,
            PdfContentByte[] canvases) {
        float x1 = position.getLeft() + 2;
        float x2 = position.getRight() - 2;
        float y1 = position.getTop() - 2;
        float y2 = position.getBottom() + 2;
        PdfContentByte canvas = canvases[PdfPTable.LINECANVAS];
        canvas.rectangle(x1, y1, x2 - x1, y2 - y1);
        canvas.stroke();
    }
}
```

Now if you do `cell.setCellEvent(new MyCellEvent());` the cell will have a custom border: a rectangle that is slightly smaller than what you'd normally have with the default border.

In your case, you don't need the `rectangle()` method. You wont to get the coordinates from the position variable and use these coordinates in a series of `moveTo()`, `lineTo()`, `stroke()` operations.